# check array index, disregarding case

Tags: php

In the given situation. How would you handle case differences?
How can you convert it to lowercase so it only focuses on the string value?

In the case bellow it should be set in other words.

```
$medi['What medication are you CURRENTLY taking?'] = null;

if(isset($medi['What medication are you currently taking?'])) {
                echo  "isset yes";
} else {
                echo "isset no";

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could manage the case for the value and use as an index

```
 $my_index  = strtolower('What medication are you CURRENTLY taking?');
 if(isset(medi[$my_index])){
 ......
 }
```

and you should compare coherent   value for index  too  using the same conversion  when you access index

Comment: Wow, quite that simple hey. Thanks

Comment: @morne, that doesn't work though if you expect 'CURRENTLY' to be capitalized. It really depends on how you set up this index.

Comment: No, Im only checking lowercase.

Comment: one question. If this index comes from the DB. How do you manipulate that? I will elaborate if needed? Because in this case its a fabricated index.

Comment: is the same .. you can selecting eg in myql : select  lower(column_name)  ...or   lowercase  the value  you select

Comment: @morne you can loop into your array if you don't know the keys, have a look at my answer ;)

Answer (score -1):

you can lowercase the key and then check if it exists.

Generic example:

```
foreach($medi as $key => $value){
    if(isset($medi[strtolower($key)])) {
       echo  "isset yes";
    } else {
       echo "isset no";
    }
}
```

Comment: Because it won't work even if there weren't syntax errors / wrong function names.

Comment: I fixed the code, the logic is working. http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/02fd798fcd06a7524645d1514f2e2825b35f25d2 @JonStirling

Comment: The question appears to be that OP wants to see if the index matches, ignoring case, i.e. $key can be an uppercase equivalent, but still echo `isset yes`. You example would not achieve this.